# Combine tuples in a loop

Tags: c++, loops, tuples

Is it possible to combine tuples via std::tuple_cat inside a for-loop, be changing the tuple, which was calculated before?

I want to use the function as follows:

```
std::tuple<int> data;
for(int i = 0; i < max; i++)
{
     /* ... some function which changes the value of data ... */
     auto temp = std::tuple_cat(temp, data); // Add the new data to the previous tuple
}
```

It's logically not compilable (temp could not be used before initialized). How can i solve this problem?

Comment: `temp` is created anew each time round the loop, so there is nothing to concatenate.

Comment: yeah i know, i just posted this code for better understanding, what i want to do

Comment: Not with runtime for loop, but with equivalent compile time one, it would be possible.

Comment: Which solution is best will depend on what you're really trying to achieve with this.

Comment: i just want to calculate some tuple and combine them in a whole new tuple

Comment: Then passing all of the individual tuples at once to the same `tuple_cat` call should work fine.

Comment: If you concatenate an element to a `std::tuple`, the resulting `std::tuple` can't possibly have the same type as the one you provided as input. There is no way for the concatenated result to be meaningfully preserved between iteration. It's not possible to achieve what you want, unless the iteration was compile-time constant.

Comment: It seems you need a dynamic container containing elements of unpredictable types. Consider using a `std::vector` of `std::any` or `std::variant` instead. Though you might find such a container difficult to work with.

Answer (score 1):

Following your logic in the `for` loop, the size of your tuple is expected to change.

It's impossible. Because the size of a tuple should be compile time constant, you can't use a same variable as tuple of different size.

Comment: isn't there a possibility by saving my datas inside of an array and then making a tuple of all elements of this array using variadic templates or something like that?

Comment: It depends on whether `max` and the types of the tuple's content can be determined at compile time.

Comment: @CplusProgrammer56 Why do you want to do that?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is something like:

```
template <typename F, std::size_t ... Is>
auto tuple_generator_seq(F&& f, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{
    const decltype(f(0u)) arr[] = {f(Is)...}; // To force order of evaluation
    return std::make_tuple(arr[Is]...);
}

template <std::size_t N, typename F>
auto tuple_generator(F&& f)
{
    return tuple_generator_seq(f, std::make_index_sequence<N>());
}

int main()
{
    auto data = 42;
    auto t = tuple_generator<5>([&](int ){ return ++data; });
    std::apply([](auto... e){ ((std::cout << e << " "), ...); }, t);
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/53f84377c44290cc)